# PackageReference and PackageReference to same project

Tags: c#, reference, csproj

Let's assume I have a library project (ProjA) and a second project (projB) that uses projA.
ProjA is published as a nuget package. Both projects have their own git repositories

In projB I have a reference to the nuget package for projA

But when I want to add some changes to both projects or check something in the library implementation, I add projA to the solutions folder in projB (using: add>Existing project). Then I need to add the project reference to projA and comment out or remove the line with the nuget reference to projA.

Is there any solution that allows me to work on both projects without manually changing the references?

Is it possible to use a project reference during development and use a nuget package reference in the published project?
Maybe, using some condition in  or  in csproj file?

Comment: maybe just have both, with `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"` and `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'"` respectively?

Comment: Thaks a lot this conditioon works perfectly

Comment: Just make sure you don't try to publish a version using an old nuget package, which you can then easily do. You can debug with the latest changes of your library project, and then when you build the version to deploy/release, you're using the nuget package. At this point you need to ensure your library project has been built, and deployed as a new nuget package version, and that your application project has been updated to use the new nuget package version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```xml
<ProjectReference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'".../>
<PackageReference Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'".../>
```